# SQL - Calcular porcentagem no mesmo select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Baseado na query abaixo, preciso adicionar a coluna **Porcentagem**, sendo ela o calculo de `Passed` em cima do `Total` mas não sei como pegar os valores desse mesmo select para inserir no cálculo.

```
SELECT 
  Data,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed,
  COUNT(*) AS Total

FROM VWDADOSFPY
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY Data DESC;
```

A tabela deve ficar assim:

```
   Data         Passed        Failed        Total       Porcentagem
2018-03-15       470            5            475          98,94%
2018-03-14       485            17           502          96,61%
2018-03-13      1631            74           1705         95,65%
```

Alguém consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando sub-query, ou seja, uma query que consulta outra query:

No Sql Server:

(se os campos não são decimais, precisa fazer os `CAST` ao menos em 1 campo, e neste caso que sempre o `Passed` e o `Total` serão inteiros, o `CAST` vem antes do `ROUND`, se não o `ROUND` sempre trará sem decimais)

```
SELECT Data, Passed, Failed, 
ROUND(((CAST(Valorx1 AS DECIMAL)*100)/(CAST(Valorx2 AS DECIMAL))),2)
FROM (
SELECT 
  Data,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM VWDADOSFPY) Alias_Tabela
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY Data DESC;
```

No MySql:

```
SELECT Data, Passed, Failed, 
ROUND(((Passed*100)/Total),2) Porcentagem, Total
FROM (
SELECT 
  Data,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM VWDADOSFPY) Alias_Tabela
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY Data DESC;
```

Regra de 3 para achar a porcentagem:

```
((Passed*100)/Total)
```

`ROUND` para arredondar com 2 casas decimais:

```
ROUND(valor,2)
```

Comment: Em T-SQL não é possível utilizar um alias criado no mesmo SELECT. Veja o erro no teste com o código que você propôs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1257d/1

Comment: Verdade @JoséDiz ! Acertei já... Pensei em uma coisa e fiz outra ! rs

Comment: Ok. O uso de subconsulta é uma das soluções. Somente acrescente a vírgula antes de  count(), ok?

Comment: Achei que era o povo de sacanagem, que entra dando -1 para medalha ! Desculpa aí ! Obrigado pela atenção !

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, só tive q ajustar algumas coisas. Mas era isso mesmo

Comment: @rmneves essa resposta não está 100% correta. Os dois digitos decimais serão sempre 00

Comment: @EstevaoLuis me explique como testou ? Aqui está normal http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43b5aa/8

Comment: @RBZ Voce está usando MySQL. A pergunta é sobre SQL Server que da um resultado diferente

Comment: Tive que usar o CAST para ter as casas decimais.

Comment: Opa, falha minha, não percebi !

Comment: Corrigido. Bem observado @EstevaoLuis. Era isso que sua resposta deveria ter, ou até somente este comentário como você mesmo fez aqui. O intuito não é um monte de respostas, mas sim, boas respostas, bem explicadas, respostas com outras formas de execução, etc... Mas falhar acontece !

Answer (score 3):

Há algumas formas.

**CTE**

```
-- código #1 v3
with totVWDADOSFPY as (
SELECT 
  Data,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
  from VWDADOSFPY
  group by Data
)
SELECT Data, Passed, Failed, Total, 
       Porcentagem= cast((Passed * 100.0 / Total) as decimal(5,2))
  from totVWDADOSFPY
  order by Data desc;
```

**CÓDIGO LINEAR**
Repete as fórmulas de cálculo de `Passed` e `Total` para calcular a porcentagem em um mesmo SELECT.

```
-- código #2 v2
SELECT Data,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed,
       COUNT(*) AS Total,
       Porcentagem= cast(SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) as decimal(5,2))
  from VWDADOSFPY
  group by Data
  order by Data desc;
```

O que o otimizador de consultas faz internamente é transformar o código #1 no código #2.

Comment: Você deu um apelido com `with` e chamou embaixo correto !?

Comment: O código #1 utiliza CTE. No caso, utiliza o _apelido_ totVWDADOSFPY, que é então posteriormente utilizado no segundo SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar uma sub-query

```
SELECT Data, Passed, Failed, CAST(ROUND((Passed * 100.0) / (Passed + Failed), 2) AS DECIMAL(5,2))
FROM (
    SELECT
    Data,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'NOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM VWDADOSFPY
    GROUP BY Data
) tab
ORDER BY Data DESC;
```

Comment: Porque usou 2 sub ?

Comment: Errei a copiar a query

Comment: @RBZ editei a minha resposta

Comment: Explique o que está propondo diferente das demais respostas. A sua está praticamente igual a minha, mas está usando o CAST, então explique o motivo, etc... e também sua conta está errada `((Passed * 100.0) / (Passed + Failed))

Comment: @RBZ Se não usar 100.0 e o cast a percentagem está errada. O resultado vai ser 98.00% em vez de 98.94%

Comment: Está correto a parte que achei que estava errada. Eu li `(Passed + Total)`

Comment: Estêvão, se quiser testar o seu código, acesse http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1257d/18 que já tem os dados prontos para uso, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo em SQL SERVER:

```
                  SELECT DISTINCT 
                   PerformanceRating                                                                                            Metric
                  ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PerformanceRating)                                                                Quantity
                  ,ROUND(((CAST(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PerformanceRating) AS DECIMAL(18,2))*100)/(CAST(COUNT(*) OVER() AS DECIMAL(18,2)))),2) [Percent]
             FROM PerformanceEvaluation
```

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular a porcentagem de um valor eu uso essa continha:

```
 declare 
 @valor     decimal (15,2)  = 200
,@percent   decimal(15,2)   = 15
,@cem       decimal(15,2)   = 100
select convert(decimal(15,2),((@valor)*(@percent/@cem/100)*@cem))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).