# Calculo de porcentagem no mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de reservas que tem ID, ORIGEM (site, app ou null) quero saber o percentual de reservas feitas pelo app e pelo site,

```
select count(id) from booking where origin = 'app' / select count(id) from booking where origin is not null * 100;
```

como faço esse cálculo no MySQL?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [SQL - Calcular porcentagem no mesmo select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283187/sql-calcular-porcentagem-no-mesmo-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa de duas consultas para isso, basta você somar a quantidade de registros que possuem a coluna `origin` igual a `app` e dividir pelo total. Algo como:

```
SELECT
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN origin = 'app' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) as resultado
FROM booking
WHERE origin IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Deu erro de sintaxe:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') / COUNT(id) as resultado
FROM booking
WHERE origin IS NOT NULL' at line 2

Comment: @DaywisonFerreiraLeal e você pesquisou o que pode ser o erro?